# Proactive failure analysis & self correction

Tags: design-patterns, architecture

Is there a way to design software applications such that it can avoid failures rather than recovering from it. Any design pattern that addresses this type of scenarios in a SOA implementation.

Answer (score 0):

***The question your answer is, young padawan!***

A solid object oriented analysis and a good software design enable you to create a less error-prone software application.
And software design patterns are usually part of a good software design.
Test driven development and defensive programming might also have a positive effect on your software quality.